# Pre measure for an infinite product of measure spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, infinite-product

Let $\{(\Omega_k, \Sigma_k, P_k)\}_{k\geq 1}$ be a sequence of probability spaces. I am trying to prove the statement below in order to use it and get a pre measure and then use the Hahn kolomogrov theorem to get a probability measure on $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \Omega_k$. The statement I want to show is:

For every $k\geq 1$, let $\{E^{(k)}_j\}_{j\geq 1}$ be a sequence in $\Sigma_k$. It is given that:

1)  $\forall j\geq 1[ \,\,\,|\{k\geq 1:E^{(k)}_j\not= \Omega_k\}|<\infty \,\,\,\,]$

2) $\prod _{k=1}^{\infty} \Omega_k=\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}(\prod _{k=1}^{\infty} E^{(k)}_j)  $ and the sets in the collection $\{\prod _{k=1}^{\infty} E^{(k)}_j\}_{j\geq 1}$ are pairwise disjoint.

then $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(\prod _{k=1}^{\infty} P_k(E^{(k)}_j))=1  $.

I tried to prove it but only succeeded in proving special cases. If anyone can give me hints, that would be great.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's introduce some notation.  Fix $n\geq 1$, and suppose $F_k\subseteq\Omega_k$ are measurable sets for each $k\geq n$ such that all but finitely many of them are $\Omega_k$.  Let $P^n(\prod_{k=n}^\infty F_k)=\prod P_k(F_k)$.  It is not hard to show that this gives rise to a finitely additive function on the Boolean algebra of finite unions of such products (you prove this in the course of constructing finite product measures).  Write $A_j=\prod_k E_j^{(k)}$; we wish to show that $\sum_j P^1(A_j)=1$.  It follows from finite additivity of $P^1$ and disjointness of the $A_j$ that $\sum_j P^1(A_j)\leq 1$.  So suppose for a contradiction that $\sum_j P^1(A_j)<1$.

Fix $x\in\Omega_1$, and write $A_j(x)=\prod_{k=2}^\infty E_j^{(k)}$ if $x\in E_j^{(1)}$, and $A_j(x)=\emptyset$ if $x\not\in E_j^{(1)}$.  Then the function $f_j(x)=P^2(A_j(x))$ is a measurable function on $\Omega_1$ for each $j$, with $\int_{\Omega_1} f_j=P^1(A_j)$.  Now consider the function $f(x)=\sum_j f_j(x)$.  Since $\sum_j P^1(A_j)<1$, $\int_{\Omega_1} f<1$, so there exists some $x_1\in\Omega_1$ such that $f(x_1)<1$, i.e. such that $\sum_j P^2(A_j(x_1))<1$.

Now repeat the argument of the previous paragraph, with the sets $A_j$ replaced by the sets $A_j(x_1)$ and $P^1$ replaced by $P^2$.  The argument above gives that there exists $x_2\in \Omega_2$ such that $\sum_j P^3(A_j(x_1,x_2))<1$ (where $A_j(x_1,x_2)$ is defined in the obvious way).  Continuing by induction, we find a sequence of points $x_k\in \Omega_k$ such that for each $k$, $\sum_j P^{k+1}(A_j(x_1,\dots,x_k))<1$.

Since $\bigcup_j A_j=\prod_k \Omega_k$, there must be some $j$ such that the sequence $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is in $A_j$.  But if $n$ is such that $E_j^{(k)}=\Omega_k$ for all $k>n$, then $A_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\prod_{k=n+1}^\infty \Omega_k$, so $P^{n+1}(A_j(x_1,\dots,x_n))=1$.  This is a contradiction, since the $x_i$ were chosen such that $\sum_j P^{n+1}(A_j(x_1,\dots,x_n))<1$.

Comment: Hello Eric. Thank you a lot for your answer. I just noticed your answer and I will need time to read it. The deadline for awarding the bounty will be done by the time I read your answer. However if your argument convinces me, I will award your answer another 100 point bounty (other than this one). Once more, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi Eric. Thank you a lot for your answer (+225 :)). I recognized the main trick of the proof (using integration to get the sequence $x_1,x_2,...$.All constructions of infinite product measure spaces i saw seem to use topology but your proof doesn't, do you have an explanation why they are using topology?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Proofs using topological conditions were known for a while before this general proof using the integration trick was found (if I remember correctly, the general result was not known until the late 1930s), and suffice for most applications.

Comment: wow. Who found out this trick ?

By the way, I am forced by the website to wait 15 hours before awarding the bounty. Once more, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oh, actually the result appears to be even later than I thought.  As far as I can find, the earliest reference is [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pja/1195573633) by Kakutani from 1943, which gives essentially the same argument as in my answer.

Comment: Hi Eric. What happens in the uncountable product case ?

Comment: I'm not sure what precise statement you are asking about, but any reasonable analogue for uncountable products should reduce to the countable product case since only countably many of the coordinates will matter for any particular chosen sequence of sets.

Comment: oops i think you are right. I guess that's why I originally formulated my question only for countable products since the uncountable case reduces to the countable. Thanks a lot for your help